# Number of symmetric relations

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let set $A=\{1,2,3\}$ 
Find number of symmetric relations that can be defined on $A$ containing ordered pairs $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ is?

Can someone give me some hint for this question?

Comment: In order to make a symmetric relation, you must choose zero or more items from the following list: (1) $(1,1)$, (2) $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$, (3) $(2,2)$, etc. up to (z) $(3,3)$. If there are $z$ items on my list, there are $2^z$ ways to create a symmetric relation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's represent $A\times A$ in a $3\times 3$ matrix (since that is the number of elements in the matrix)
$\begin{bmatrix}
& \color{teal}1 
& \color{teal}2
& \color{teal}3 \\\\
\color{deeppink}1 &
({\color{deeppink}1}, {\color{teal}1}) &
\color{grey}{(1, 2)} &
({\color{deeppink}1}, {\color{teal}3}) \\\\
\color{deeppink}2 &
\color{grey}{(2, 1)} &
({\color{deeppink}2}, {\color{teal}2}) &
({\color{deeppink}2}, {\color{teal}3}) \\\\
\color{deeppink}3 &
({\color{deeppink}3}, {\color{teal}1}) &
({\color{deeppink}3}, {\color{teal}2}) &
({\color{deeppink}3}, {\color{teal}3})
\end{bmatrix}$

Note that the first row/column are header row/column and are for reference only.

Now, by the definition of symmetric relations, selecting an element $(a_i, a_j)$ automatically selects $(a_j, a_i)$, where $i \ne j$, and so there is no such restriction on the principal diagonal elements, however since they got no ‘mirror image element’, we need to consider both of them separately.

#### For Non-principal diagonals elements:

There are total $n^2 - n = 3^2 - 3 = 6$ non-diagonal elements (total - diagonal elements).
Since selecting one element automatically selects its ‘mirror image element’, lets only consider half of these elements, those we have choice for (take either lower/upper half triangle elements).
Since we **need** to select the pair $(1,2)$ (if considering upper-half triagle) or $(2,1)$ (if considering lower-half triangle)
Number of such elements: $2$ (for either lower/upper-half triangle)
For all these elements, we have two choices, either take it or leave it, so we get total number of ways to select these: $2^2$ = 4

#### For Principal-diagonal elements:

There are total $n = 3$  such elements on the principal-diagonals. Again number of ways to select them will become $2^n = 2^3 = 8$.

#### Final Result:

Number of ways to select these elements:

 (Number of ways of selecting principal diagonal elements) $\times$ (Number of ways of selecting non-principal diagonal elements)
 $= 8\times4$

$= 32$

Hence, there are total $32$ such possible relations on the set $A$.